# git force local repo to lf eol

Tags: git, eol

i want a local git repo to use always lf eol, no matter what comes from the server.
But i don't want this behaviour for every repository, just for one. I'm using tortoise git, if this makes it easier.

my .git/config looks like this

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    eol = lf
    autocrlf = false
    safecrlf = false
```

But there is still crlf applied to the files. I'm not sure if i did something wrong in this config file, or if i need to run a update command that updates the existing files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update/create under `<repo_path>/.git/info/.gitattributes`

"The attributes allow a fine-grained control, how the line endings are converted. Here is an example that will make Git normalize `.txt`, `.vcproj` and `.sh` files, ensure that `.vcproj` files have `CRLF` and `.sh` files have `LF` in the working directory, and prevent `.jpg` files from being normalized regardless of their content" [gitattributes](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion)

```
*           text=auto
*.txt       text
*.vcproj    text eol=crlf
*.sh        text eol=lf
*.jpg       -text
```

Afterwards do : `git add --renormalize .`